# how to save Tensorflow Keras checkpoint to pb file

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

Anyone knows how to save tensorflow keras checkpoint file into .pb binary file for serving?

I am not 100% sure how to implement this.

Do I need to declare `tf.keras.backend.get_session()` to save graph and pb file?

In sum,
1. Method to save pb file via `tf.keras`
or
2. Any approaches using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link on how to use [keras with tensorflow](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html). Basically you should get the tensorflow model from keras (`K.get_session()` and `K.get_graph().graph`) and use the [tensorflow methotd](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) to save it.

Comment: I already saw this articles but when I saved keras model, it needs to reload again via keras model but I am not sure how to do it. Following instructions are not helpful related to pb save files. Is there any simple example tf.keras save pb examples around here?